# how to loop data to different div in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, activerecord, actionview

- if we have 4 data record in database, the Big Box & Small Box loop will generate 4 times of its data.
- So how to generate data (first record only) for the Big Box div and the rest (3 more left) go to Small Box div (without the first record).

View

```
<div class="row">
  <% @firstbox.each do |first| %>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Big Box <%= first.title %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
      <% @firstbox.each do |second| %>
        <div class="col-md-3">Small Box <%= second.title %></div>
        <!--
          <div class="col-md-3">Small Box <%= second.title %></div>
          <div class="col-md-3">Small Box <%= second.title %></div>
          <div class="col-md-3">Small Box <%= second.title %></div>
        -->
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: class BoxController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @firstbox = Course.all
  end
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array#shift](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-shift) to get the first element of your array

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    Big Box <%= @firstbox.shift.title %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
      <% @firstbox.each do |other| %>
        <div class="col-md-3">Small Box <%= other.title %></div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If your firstbox is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` you have to convert @firstbox to an Array first. @firstbox = @firstbox.to_a

Comment: if we use shift, how can we show its data? for the rest its working, which can display all data (except the shift). Thanks

Comment: Given a=["elem1","elem2","elem3","elem4"] : a.shift return "elem1" and a == [ "elem2","elem3","elem4"]

Comment: well, its working but can be used for only 1 time. 
If we use more than one. Ex: 
<%= firstbox.shift.title %> 
<%= firstbox.shift.name %> 
<%= firstbox.shift.mail %> 
<%= firstbox.shift.status %> 
<%= firstbox.shift.description %> 

And it will destroy each loop (blank)

Please help, thanks

Comment: Yes, it's work only once. You have to use a variable : first_item = @firstbox.shift and use first_item.name first_time.email ....